# Ошибка с функцией map. C++

Tags: c++, map

Здравствуйте. Выдает непонятную ошибку, как исправить?
Скриншот:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот исходный код:

```
string translator(string x, int language) {
    string Return;
    map <char, char> mapEng{{ 'q', 'й' },{ 'w', 'ц' },{ 'e', 'у' },{ 'r', 'к' },{ 't', 'е' },{ 'y', 'н' },{ 'u', 'г' },{ 'i', 'ш' },{ 'o', 'щ' },{ 'p', 'з' },{ 't', 'е' },{ '[', 'х' },{ ']', 'ъ' },
    { 'a', 'ф' },{ 's', 'ы' },{ 'd', 'в' },{ 'f', 'а' },{ 'g', 'п' },{ 'h', 'р' },{ 'j', 'о' },{ 'k', 'л' },{ 'l', 'д' },{ ';', 'ж' },{ '\'', 'э' },{ '\\', '\\' },
    { 'z', 'я' },{ 'x', 'ч' },{ 'c', 'с' },{ 'v', 'м' },{ 'b', 'и' },{ 'n', 'т' },{ 'm', 'ь' },{ ',', 'б' },{ '.', 'ю' },{ '/', '.' } };
    switch (language) {
    case 1:
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
            char a = mapEng.find(x[i]);
            Return += a;
        }
    case 2: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: find возвращает итератор, а не char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы пытаетесь получить, предоставляет метод `at`, а не метод `find`. Т.е. не

```
char a = mapEng.find(x[i]);
```

а

```
char a = mapEng.at(x[i]);
```

Надо только помнить, что в случае, когда `x[i]` отсутствует в `mapEng`, будет выброшено исключение. Устраивает это вас или нет - вам решать, ибо из вашего кода не ясно, что вы планируете делать в таких ситуациях.

Comment: Благодарю. А как определить, что это исключение? Какого типа будет выдавать ошибку?

Comment: Изнутри метода `at` будет сделано `throw  std::out_of_range(...)`. Если вы у себя не сделаете `catch` для этого `throw`, то программа просто упадет.

Answer (score 0):

как уже сказали в комментариях, результат `mapEng.find()` нужно сохранить в итератор

правильный вариант:

```
string translator(string x, int language) {
    string Return;
    map <char, char> mapEng{...};
    switch (language) {
    case 1:
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
            map <char, char>::const_iterator a = mapEng.find(x[i]);
            Return += a->second;
        }
    case 2: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не помешает еще проверить результат.

Comment: @Croessmah это излишне